# Intensifying "is" using "do"

Tags: verbs, intensifiers

A strange question: is the form 'do is' correct? For example:

> HTML is not a programming language. On the other hand, JavaScript, that can be used in a HTML document, do is a programming language.

Comment: "*an* HTML" (go by the sound). I can't see how "do" makes any sense here. Is there some reason for using it?

Comment: By the way, where did you get the "do + be" idea from in the first place?

Comment: The "do+be" is connected with emphasizing that despite HTML is not a programming language, it is able to have a code written in programming language included. But this question was mostly about curiosity :D.

Comment: `do is a programming language` means there's a programming language called "do" (why not? [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)) already exists :)).

Comment: @user3169 I always thought "HTML" was pronounced like "hot meal", as in "Will code HTML for a hot meal"... (Paweł, please ignore this! user3169 is, of course, right! ;) )

Comment: *H* doesn't start with a vowel sound for me, @user3169. I'm Irish.

Comment: @TRiG Interesting... How do you pronounce H when saying the letters H,T,M,L?

Comment: @user3169 With a *h*, of course. ;) Seriously, it's something like *haitch*. I've been told that in the North, the pronunciation is a shibboleth.

Answer (score 13):

No. do + be by itself is not a valid construction.

One of many possible replacements for your incorrect construction is:

> HTML is not a programming language. On the other hand, JavaScript, that can be used in an HTML document, really is a programming language.

There is a **whole class** of words used to intensify verbs, adjectives or adverbs in some way. These are the **intensifiers**. Explaining all of them takes up more room than can reasonably fit in an answer. Just look up each intensifier in a dictionary.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/intensifiers-very-at-all

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/intensifiers

Comment: *Don't be a nuisance.  Do be on time for class.* Sometimes *do + be* is grammatical.

Comment: @snailboat, grammatically correct but not especially idiomatic - *Be on time for class* would be more commonly used, mainly because most people think "do be" sounds like something Sinatra would sing.

Answer (score 8):

"do" can be used to intensify almost any English verb, in which case it is often written in *italics* and spoken with heavy emphasis:

> Despite the tedious grammar, I *do* appreciate English.

However, "do" cannot precede an auxiliary verb, where auxiliary verbs include be, will, can, may, etc.  The same kind of intensification can still be done, but only by intensifying the auxiliary verb itself:

> Unlike HTML, Javascript *is* a programming language.

(EDIT: On a side note, even if 'do' were acceptable, the standard conjugation would be `does be` and not `do is`.)

Comment: There is an exception, though, and that is in dialects of English where "be" indicates the habitual (such as Hiberno-English, the closely-related Newfoundland dialect, and African American Vernacular English). That is to say that you *may* hear "do be" (not "do is" or any other normal conjugated form), but it will not be in a standard dialect. So, in some contexts, *HTML do be a programming language* would be correct, or at least as correct as people who require Turing completeness allow it to be, but non-standard.

Comment: And in "[Pirate English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pirate-english)", which is a [fictionalised](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171741/uncertain-whether-pirate-talk-be-authentically-or-mockingly-archaic) caricature of the [Somerset / West Country accent](http://dialectblog.com/2011/05/24/pirate-accent/) and dialect, for example from a Garfield comic: ["Arrr, it do be a land-lubber who be shovin' lasagna in his face"](http://www.quotes.net/mquote/35625)

Comment: *Does be* does not sound natural or correct to me (AmE).

Answer (score 2):

"do is" is wrong here.  In this case it would have to be "does be" but while being formed according to the rules of the trade, it would still end up being wrong.

Interesting enough, you *can* use this combination for the imperative mode: "do be a nice guy and fetch me a beer" is actually fine unless you are a teetotaler.

I don't really know whether there is an actual rule at play here or whether it just managed escaping into the vernacular because of sounding least contorted among its equally logical but impermissible cousins.

Comment: *Does be* does not sound natural or correct to me (AmE).